# How to apply function elementwise in Julia?

Tags: julia

There's a function `h(x) = ([1, x]' * [2, 3])[1]`

Let's suppose I'd like to plot it and get `X` and `Y`. One possible way to do it is following

```
X = [1 2 3]
Y = [h(xi) for xi in X]
```

But, it seems like it's also possible to do the same using elementwise operator in Julia?

Unfortunately prefixing the function with the dot `.h(X)` doesn't work.

Comment: Is `map(h, X)` what you're looking for here?

Comment: It is a general question, or do you want a elementwise solution for your example? I believe your example can be vectorized.. But for generic approaches `map` is the solution as @niczky12 suggests.

Comment: Yes, I've asked about the general approach.

Comment: It would be useful to get up-to-date answers for Julia 1.X.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**update**: `f.(x)` syntax was merged and avaliable in julia v0.5, see [the document](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions.html#man-vectorized-1) or [WIP](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/15032).

[@vectorize_1arg](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/fdbcdf78bf0106e609a8d83b9e896d2d11bae594/base/operators.jl#L473) in julia's Base can make Arrays acceptable by your functions. Wrap your `h` with this macro may solve the problem.

Here is an example from [julia document](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#vectorized-operators-and-functions)

```
julia> square(x) = x^2
square (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @vectorize_1arg Number square
square (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> methods(square)
# 4 methods for generic function "square":
square{T<:Number}(::AbstractArray{T<:Number,1}) at operators.jl:380
square{T<:Number}(::AbstractArray{T<:Number,2}) at operators.jl:381
square{T<:Number}(::AbstractArray{T<:Number,N}) at operators.jl:383
square(x) at none:1

julia> square([1 2 4; 5 6 7])
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   4  16
 25  36  49
```

If you are looking for a more "elegant" method, [here is a discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8450) about add new grammars for this problem.